# Meta account not showing on other sites.

Tags: discussion, bug

Good day to all. My problem is, that all of my other accounts are showing on other Stack Exchange sites, but this one isn't.

Link to other Site account: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9621927/arihan-sharma-ray-lawson-ps?tab=summary.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Maybe you have hidden it here https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/hidecommunities/402819

Comment: No, I just checked. No hidden communities.

Comment: Now the list contains your MSE account. Probably, caching issue. Because you just created your MSE acc.

Comment: Thank you yes now it does indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've just created an account on MSE. The information about your new MSE account wasn't transferred to other SE sites.

Information like this isn't transferred instantly to other sites (to reduce loads). So, SE sites use some sort of caching. You just need to wait a little bit.